# What's the difference between `:path-param` and `{path-param}` in Java Spark?

Tags: java, url-routing, spark-java

I'm working on a REST server built with Java Spark, and I was wondering about the difference between the following two syntaxes for defining path parameters, using `:path-parameter` vs `{path-parameter}`:

```
path("/containers/:container-id", () -> { ...} )

path("/shipments/{shipment-id}", () -> { ... } )
```

At one point, when querying the path parameters on the path `/{handler-id}` (which is nested inside `/v1` and `/handlers`), I had to change the syntax from the `:` form to the `{}` form to get Spark to not return `null` when querying the parameters for `handler-id`.

So what's the difference between these two syntaxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only syntax for defining a parameter in a path is `:path-param`.

Querying the value of this parameter is done by `String paramVal = request.params(":path-param")` (the colon is optional when querying).

Or, if you want to get a map with all the parameters names-values you'll go `request.params();`

I'm not sure about why you got null when querying your param, but I'm guessing you used `request.queryParams(":path-param");`. But this API is used not to query a path-params like you wanted, but to query a **query params** which are parameters in the form of path like `/api/users?userId=1234`.

Summary

```
Path Definition  URL in browser                Query
---------------  ----------------------------  -----------------------------------
/api/users/:id   <host>/api/users/1234         request.params("id") ==> 1234
/api/users       <host>/api/users?id=1234      request.queryParams("id") ==> 1234
```

- Note that the returned value is always a `String` and you'll have to cast if needed.