# Spark Java: POST call not working correctly

Tags: spark-java

**Problem:** POST's Request parameters coming in as Request body, NOT as request parameters.

I am calling a spark Java web service with this syntax below.

**http://localhost:8080/submitCustomer?custId#4&Name=Fredj"**

---

Spark Java tells me this:

Request IP 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 
Request Verb POST
Request Received:custId#4&Name=FredJ (-->Request.body())
URL Received:http://localhost:8080/submitCustomer

---

Any ideas why these variables are coming in as part of the Request body instead of request parameters?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How do you check these parameters? Using what API functions?

Comment: It seems that the POST putting the parameters in the Request body is perfectly normal, or so I'm told. In the past, I've always gotten the POST variables using the getParameter() type methods.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.queryParams(..)` API to retrieve the query params from the path.

Example:

For the URL `http://localhost:8080/submitCustomer?abc=123`, a route for the path `/submitCustomer` can do this:

```
String val = request.queryParams("abc");
System.out.println(val);
```

It will print `123`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315009/6032010) for more details.

I just not sure about your params in the URL. You wrote the path is `custId#4&Name=Fredj`. Are you sure it's not `custId=4&Name=Fredj` (`=` instead of `#`)?